# Backbone fragment in pushState behavior straight

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pushstate

I am a newbie in backbone.js, i try to write demo to understand about backbone.js but i have problem in Backbone fragment when i set pushState true in Backbone history . Here is my case

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.route(/^users\/friends$/i, "hellobackbone")
    }
    hellobackbone: function() {
         alert(Backbone.history.fragment)
    }
});
```

When I am in address: `localhost/users/friends`.
I press in `<a href="#hello">hello</a>`

It alert two twice with `users/friends` and `users/friends#hello`. I just only want call with routes users/friends(see my regular expression). I don't know why this happen. I find around   backbone.js and some site from googles but no help:((